# Recursive search through tree without passing object

Tags: java, recursion, tree, stack-unwinding

I'm trying to search for a node in a non-binary tree without actually passing a node to the search method.

Each node has a `name` variable. The `findChild()` method takes a name, and searches through the tree it was called on to find the node with that name.

To do the recursive search, I call `findChild()` on the child node rather than passing the child node to the `findChild()` method. Print statements show me that the method gets down through the tree, but the `result` variable gets set to null as the stack is unwinded, so the method always returns null. I understand why it's doing this, but I don't understand how to unwind this type of recursion. Any help is appreciated!

My `findChild()` method:

```
public FileNode findChild(String name) {
    FileNode result = null;
        for (FileNode child : this.getChildren()) {
            if (child.getName() == name) {
                return child;
            } else {
                child.findChild(name);
            }
        }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: First of all you should always use `.equals` to compare Strings instead of `==`. `==` will check if the same object is reference whereas `.equals`will check whether the strings are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will the following small change help? Your else condition is never assigning a value.

```
public FileNode findChild(String name) {
    FileNode result = null;
        for (FileNode child : this.getChildren()) {
            if (child.getName() == name) {
                result = child;
                break;
            } else {
                result = child.findChild(name);
                if (result != null)
                    break;
            }
        }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're throwing away the result of `FileNode#findChild` in the `else` block

Try this

```
if (child.getName().equals(name)) {
    return child;
} else {
    FileNode childResult = child.findChild(name);
    if (childResult != null) {
        return childResult;
    }
}
```