# Recursively search through a Tree in Java

Tags: java, recursion, tree

I have a non-binary Tree with nodes defined in the following way:

```
public class TreeNode{
private String label;
private TreeNode[] children;

public TreeNode(String label){
     this.label = label;
     children = new TreeNode[9]
}
```

So each node has a label and an array of size 9 which holds its 9 children.
Now in my tree class, I want to define a find method that will find a node with a specific label. This is what I could come up with:

```
public TreeNode find(String label, TreeNode node) {
    TreeNode result = null;
    if (node.getLabel().equals(label)) {
        return node;
    } else {
        if (node.hasChildren()){
            for (int i = 0; i< node.getChildren().length; i++){
                if (node.getChildren()[i].getLabel().equals(label)) {
                    result = node.getChildren()[i];
                    break;
                else
                    return find(label, node.getChildren()[i];
           }
    return result;
}
```

And the problem with this is that it just goes a level deeper everytime without looking through the siblings of the "node" I provide to the method.

I'm sure the solution is trivial but I just can't seem to catch it.

There is a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40156565/recursive-search-through-tree-without-passing-object) and I think their issue is also similar but I can't seem to translate the provided solution to my application.

What am I missing? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `return` inside the `for` loop without checking the returned value of the recursive call. Also, apply the recursive call to all items in the loop unconditionally.

```
for (int i = 0; i < node.getChildren().length; i++){
    result = find(label, node.getChildren()[i];
    if(result != null) {
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That did it. Do you recommend any good resources to learn recursion?

Comment: @doddy Ah, glad to hear. Well, I always felt recursion was easier to understand than iteration (in most cases). I learned purely through experimentation and the study of common recursive operations with trees and lists. There are a lot of sources online, SO being one of them. Look at tree traversal and operations if you're interested.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ the easiest one is: `to understand recursion, one have to understand recursion first`